# Testing with an infinite loop, is my application timing out? (C# using a PLC hardware input)

Tags: c#, for-loop, while-loop, plc

So I am testing this script here to determine which input is being read into my C# application. I am doing the following that is working at the moment

1: setting breakpoints at each if statement

2: using a 24V wire to manually turn each input on the PLC high

3: viewing the message box and insuring it is reading the right input

HOWEVER, when I remove the breakpoints and just keep the program running indefinitely, and manually try to turn on one of the inputs with a wire to test....none of the message boxes appear, is my application timing out, what am I missing? I'm not new to programming but definitely out of my environment working in C# so any help would be appreciated.

```
while (true)
            {
                for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                {
                    SomeGlobalVariables.inputs = master.ReadInputs(1, 0, 6);
                    if (SomeGlobalVariables.inputs[0] == true)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("port 1");
                    }
                    if (SomeGlobalVariables.inputs[1] == true)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("port 2");
                    }
                    if (SomeGlobalVariables.inputs[2] == true)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("port 3");
                    }
                    if (SomeGlobalVariables.inputs[3] == true)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("port 4");
                    }
                    if (SomeGlobalVariables.inputs[4] == true)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("port 5");
                    }

            }
```

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what `master.ReadInputs` does. But you are in a [tight loop](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tight_loop) which doesn't help.

Comment: It's a call from the nModBus library, i do see what you are saying and am googling tight loops now :)

Answer (score 1):

The i variable in the for loop is not used, you might as well remove the for loop.
Then set a breakpoint at:

```
    if (SomeGlobalVariables.inputs[0] == true)
```

and check what SomeGlobalVariables.inputs contains. Also, i goes from 0 to 5, which are 6 values, but you're only checking on 5 values. Maybe your could replace the indexes in the brackets by i:

```
    if (SomeGlobalVariables.inputs[i] == true)
        MessageBox.Show("port " + i);
```

and put the read function outside the for loop in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the for loop...it came from a previous test that I was doing, because I couldn't actually get SomeGlobalVariables.inputs[i] to read the write value....but duly noted, I will try again and clean up the code according to your recommendations